# Using the Animated API correctly in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-animated

I am fairly new to Animated API in react native. I went through a lot of tutorials for using animation API and it seems in every one of them the elements are positioned as absolute, is it necessary to position the element absolute ?

Also I made a piece of animation but it looks glitchy, I think the view after the textinput donot have absolute as position which might be causing the issue. Is it possible to do the animation I'm trying to while keeping the textinput position absolute but other elements positioned with flexbox?

[image]

Here is the code

```
handleFocus = () => {
console.log('starting animation');
this.setState({
  isFocused: true
});
Animated.timing(this.isFromViewFocused, {
  toValue: 1,
  duration: 300
}).start();
}

handleBlur = () => {
console.log('Blurring');
this.setState({
  isFocused: false
});
Animated.timing(this.isFromViewFocused, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 300
}).start();
}

render() {
const labelStyle = {
  position: this.state.isFocused === true ? 'absolute' : 'relative',
  alignItems: 'center',
  width: this.isFromViewFocused.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.45, DEVICE_WIDTH]
  }),
  left: this.isFromViewFocused.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [DEVICE_WIDTH * 0.03, 0]
  }),
  marginBottom: this.isFromViewFocused.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 80]
  }),
  top: this.isFromViewFocused.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [10, 0]
  }),
  borderWidth: this.isFromViewFocused.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 5]
  }),
  borderColor: 'black',
  paddingTop: this.state.isFocused === true ? 20 : 0
 };
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'>

      <Animated.View
      style={labelStyle}
      >

        <TextInput
        onFocus={this.handleFocus}
        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        style={{
          borderColor: 'black',
          borderWidth: 1,
          width: '90%'
        }}
        >
          <Text>Hey Text</Text>
        </TextInput>
      </Animated.View>

      <Animated.View
      style={[styles.LocationContainer,
        { marginTop: this.isFromViewFocused.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [20, 80]
        })
      }
    ]}>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `absolute` positioning combined with `left`, `top`, `bottom`, `right` is bad for performances. That's why your animations looks "glitchy".

You'd be better using transforms so your component stays `relative` and native optimizations can be made (same as CSS3 transforms).

Also, when using not native-optimizable properties (such as the one you use) you cannot set `useNativeDriver` to true. Which makes performances even worse.

To add with that, you cannot (or shouldn't) interpolate based on a boolean. AnimatedJS provides you with an `Animated.Value` class that aims to make it easier to interpolate stuff.

Here is a simpler example to Animated:

```
export class MyAnimatedComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    animatedValue: new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  focus = () => {
    const { animatedValue } = this.state;
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      duration: 280,
      toValue: 1,

      // This will make your animation glitch-free/performant.
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }

  blur = () => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      duration: 140,
      toValue: 0,

      // This will make your animation glitch-free/performant.
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }

  render () {
    const { animatedValue } = this.state;
    const animatedStyles = {
      transform: [
        {
          // Move the div by 120px to the left when value === 1
          translateX: animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, -120],

            // Tells Animated to never go outside of the outputRange
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
          }) 
        },
        {
          translateY: animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, -50],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
          })
        }
      ]
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Animated.View style={animatedStyles} onFocus={onFocus} onBlur={onBlur}>
          I'm some content into an Animated div.
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a saviour! Thanks!

Comment: No problems, maybe you can mark the answer as resolved ✅ ? ;)

Comment: FYI: Missing `{` and `}` for the config object passed into the interpolate function. I.e. it should be e.g. `{ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [0, -120], extrapolate: 'clamp' }`.  Suggested edit queue is full so I couldn't edit myself.